# Passing list of boxed primitives to Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am struggling with Lists as method parameters at Google Cloud Endpoints.

The documentations says that

> The supported parameter types are the following:
>
> - java.util.Collection of a parameter type

I tried to do it this way, but it just do not work.
Basic endpoint method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "testMethod", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void testMethod(@Named("longList") List<Long> longList) {
    for (Long aLong : longList) {
        if (aLong < 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You can't do it");
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this method using API Exploler the generated URL is:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/billEndpoint/v1/testMethod?longList=5&longList=6
```

And the method is executed correctly.

But when Android library is used the url is changed to:

```
http://APP_ENGINE_BACKEND:8080/_ah/api/billEndpoint/v1/testMethod/5,6
```

and the endpoint return 404 code.

It is possible to have List as method parameter and if it is what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add @Nullable annotation to your method, that will turn your collection-type parameter from a path into a query parameter.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#nullable

Comment: Well... This worked, but it is very strange way to resolve this problem. It really looks like "It's not a bug, it's a feature" thing. Especially that parameters at my methods cannot be null.

Comment: It is a little weird because the annotation is called `@Nullable` but a more appropriate name should have been something like `@QueryParameter` because using this annotation changes the treatment of the parameter in the endpoint url from being a path parameter to a query parameter - so the url format changes from endpointurl/param to endpointurl?parameter=param

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to also use set() methods for parameters instead of the normal method params. So instead of api.testMethod(longList).execute();  You would do api.testMethod().setLongList(longList).execute()

Answer (score 1):

A more direct way is to add a path property to the API_METHOD annotation and not include the List parameter in the path. As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types): "If path is specified, parameters can be made query parameters by not including them in the path"

In your case it should look like:

@ApiMethod(name = "testMethod", path="testMethod" httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)