# Google App Engine Integer Array Parameter

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm trying to pass in an int[] as a parameter into my endpoint (that uses Objectify).  Here is the endpoint method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getThemeDetailsFromList")
public CollectionResponse<Theme> getThemeDetailsFromList(@Named("ids") int[] ids) {
    List<Theme> execute = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int id:ids) {
        execute.add(getTheme(id));
    }
    return CollectionResponse.<Theme> builder().setItems(execute).build();
}
```

And here is the portion of code from my app:

```
                        Set<String> themes = tm.getFavoritesByID();
                        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (String id: themes) {
                            ids.add(Integer.parseInt(id));
                        }
                        results = endpoint.getIconThemeDetailsFromList(ids).execute();
```

I tried passing in an int[] as ids but it won't let me and only accepts an ArrayList.  When I run the app, i get the following return error:

```
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
> Bad Request {   "code": 400,   "errors": [
>     {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "location": "ids[0]",
>       "locationType": "parameter",
>       "message": "Invalid integer value: '3,1,5'.",
>       "reason": "invalidParameter"
>     }   ],   "message": "Invalid integer value: '3,1,5'." }
```

ids is an arraylist of {3,1,5}.  I don't know why it makes me pass in a List and why it gives me the return error.

Comment: Check this question for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359099/passing-list-of-boxed-primitives-to-google-cloud-endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up creating a new class with my requirements:

```
public class BatchThemeRequest {
private int[] ids;

public void setIds(int[] ids) {
    this.ids = ids;
    }

//code here
}
```

I edited the backend to be:

```
public CollectionResponse<Theme> retrieveBatchWithCursor(BatchThemeRequest batchThemeRequest) {
// code here
}
```

In the app I would create a new BatchThemeRequest and add my int[] into via setIds();