# Appengine endpoint interprits List<Long> argument incorrectly

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a GAE endpoint method which accepts a `List<Long>` argument.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getBills")
public List<EndpointBill> getBills(@Named("emailAddress") String emailAddress, @Named("billIds") List<Long> billIds) {
}
```

I call above endpoint method from an android app like below (with help of generated client lib).

```
List<Long> billsToFetch = new ArrayList<>();
//Populate billsToFetch
EndpointBillCollection endpointBillCollection = myEndpoint.getBills("test@test.com", billsToFetch).execute();
```

But, endpoint throws an exception if `billsToFetch` list contains more than one element.

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "billIds[0]",
      "locationType": "parameter",
      "message": "Invalid long value: '1,2'.",
      "reason": "invalidParameter"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid long value: '1,2'."
}
```

The error is `Invalid long value: '1,2'.`. As I observed, `1,2` value above is the bill IDs concatanated with a `,` character (billsToFetch contains 1 and 2. If billsToFetch contained 5 and 6, error message becomes `Invalid long value: '5,6'.`).

How should I fix this? Or, doesn't endpoints support `List<Long>` argument?

Comment: Is java.util.List directly supported?  According to: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#supported_parameter_types, the closest I can see is "Any array or java.util.Collection of a parameter type".

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359099/passing-list-of-boxed-primitives-to-google-cloud-endpoint

Comment: @dyoo Yes, since `List` implements `java.util.Collection` it is supported.

Comment: @dyoo, As given in the answer you pointed out, I annotated `billIds` as `@Nullable` and then it worked. My java client code changed a bit bit it works now.

Comment: @konqi, I have mentioned how I call the endpoint in the question. I use generated java client library in my android app to call endpoint.